# Require context `getStore`

Tags: reactjs, fluxible

I meet a little mistake with **Fluxible@0.4.10**:

`` Warning: Failed Context Types: Required context `getStore` was not specified in `StoreConnector`. Check the render method of `NavIndexItemTheme`.
/client-interface/node_modules/fluxible/addons/connectToStores.js:48
                    storeInstances[storeName] = this.context.getStore(store);
                                                             ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function ``

In fact, I have this:

```
components
          |_NavIndexItemTheme.jsx
...
templates
         |_tp1
              |_node_modules
              |             |_react
              |_Index.tpl.jsx
```

In **Index.tpl.jsx**:

```
import React from "react";
import NavIndexItemTheme from "../../components/NavIndexItemTheme";

export default function(props) {
    return (
       <div className="index">
         <div className="wrapper flex fdc fas">
            <h1>Hello</h1>
            <NavIndexItemTheme />
          </div>
        </div>
    );
 }
```

If I delete the **node_modules** folder to **tp1** directory, there isn't mistake. Why this directory causes mistake !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not keep multiple `node_modules` folders inside of one project, this introduces ambiguity to your dependency resolution, which leads to mess. Looks like your Fluxible modules are of different versions than the one used in project root and `NavIndexItemTheme`.

1. Use at least Fluxible 0.4.11, where [context.getStore was added](https://github.com/yahoo/fluxible/commit/b15941f9e21c521625ef6d75ef5ad0edea0712c2).
2. Remove `templates/tp1/node_modules`
3. Ensure that your higher-order component (usually `Application`) is wrapped in a `provideContext()` function from `fluxible/addons/`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact, **templates** is now a package